# Gmail-like menu collapse and expand

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to mimic the new Gmail menu-collapse style.  So when a menu is very long (over a certain height in pixels) I want to collapse it to a predetermined height.  When the exposed menu area is hovered over, I want to expand the menu to the original menu height.  When leaving the area again, reduce the height to the predetermined... rinse and repeat.  This is the jQuery I have so far:

```
/**
 * @author Les Peabody
 */
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".collapsible").css('height','200px');
        $(".collapsible").mouseenter(function () {
            $(".collapsible").animate({
                height: '400px'
            },300, function () {

            });
            });
        $(".collapsible").mouseleave(function () {
            $(".collapsible").animate({
                height: '200px'
            },300, function () {

            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Essentially what I'm doing is any element with the class "collapsible" is assigned this functionality.  The problem I'm running into is I don't know how to go about restoring the original height of the affected menu.  Any tips?

EDIT: Following the tips received from the accepted answer below, I now have this code that is working.

```
$(".collapsible").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).switchClass("constrained","unconstrained",300);
    return false;
});
$(".collapsible").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).switchClass("unconstrained","constrained",300);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to just make style differences, I would limit the JQuery to remove/add a class `constrained` and set the styles in CSS.

```
#menu.constrained {
  max-height: 200px;
  ...
}
```

Even better, you could skip JQuery altogether by targeting `#menu:hover ...` instead of `#menu.constrained ...`!

People overuse JQuery.

---

inb4 animations: there are CSS animations, and they can even tap into advanced system resources like graphic acceleration.

Comment: You beat me to it :) The problem with that is cross-browser compatibility.  I'm rocking the CSS animations and transition effects in -webkit and -moz, but IE is gimped.  JQuery assures cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: I think one can still animate the application of a class, with JQuery UI. But I personally feel inclined to go with progressive enhancement, rather than graceful degradation. With the added value of pushing for standards - let's build our own future! :)

Comment: Yes! That was not what I meant, but the effect seems to be the same as I would expect from using animate with a class, according to this: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ `Note: The jQuery UI project extends the .animate() method by allowing some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated. The project also includes mechanisms for specifying animations through CSS classes rather than individual attributes.`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should restore the div with `height: auto`.

```
$(".collapsible").animate({
    height: 'auto'
},300);
```

Comment: Applying this in the mouseenter handler has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
var originalHeight;
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".collapsible").css('height','200px');
        $(".collapsible").mouseenter(function () {
            originalHeight = $(this).height();
            $(".collapsible").animate({
                height: '400px'
            },300, function () {

            });
            });
        $(".collapsible").mouseleave(function () {
            $(".collapsible").animate({
                height: originalHeight;
            },300, function () {

            });
        });
    });
```

so with this you save the original height of the element, before changeit, and then you restore it!